# what fetch return when "then" statement is used and when without "then"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, fetch

```
 const res3 = await fetch(url2, {
      method: "GET",
      header: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
       console.log("Success:", data);
     })
    .catch((err) => console.log("thown error-->" + err));
    
    console.log(res3);
     const response=await res3.json() //erroneous line
    console.log(response);
```

**here res3 = undefined is printed**

> and when the below code is executed

```
 const res3 = await fetch(url2, {
          method: "GET",
          header: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
        });
        
    const response=await res3.json()
    console.log(response);
```

**response = [object , Object] is printed on console**

> and when try to access the response as response.obj where the backend sends back the response as:
> res.json({
> obj:data,
> msg:"Success"
> })

Comment: Please clarify your question, make it more clear

Comment: In the first code example, value of `res` depends on what happens to the promise returned by `fetch`. If it fulfils, then value of `res` depends on what you returns from the callback function of the last `then` method, which currently implicitly returns undefined. If the fetch promise is rejected, then value of `res` depends on what you return from the callback function of the `catch` method.